# React Navigation - access to tabBarOnPress of the createBottomTabNavigator having a createStackNavigator nested

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have

```
screen: createBottomTabNavigator(
        {
          firstTab: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
              firstStack: {
                screen: firstStackScreen
              },
              SecondStack: {
                screen: SecondStackScreen
                }
              }
            }),
          secondTab: {
            screen: SecondTabScreen,
          }
```

Inside the firstTabScreen, I want to access to tabBarOnPress function. I have no problem with having access to the tabBarOnpress function inside the secondTab screen but I can't inside the firstStackScreen. Is there a way to do this?

```
class firstStackScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      tabBarOnPress({ navigation, defaultHandler }) {
        ....
      }
    };
  };
}
```

I know I can have access to it inside my App screen where I define those tabs and stacks but in order for my code to work I need to do this inside the firstStackScreen.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to access navigationOptions of the parent inside nested stackNavigation, which won't work as they explained in [documentation v3.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-stack-contains-a-tab-navigator-and-you-want-to-set-the-title-on-the-stack-header)

Instead they mention in a similar example, how u can achieve it.

it goes something like that

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Feed: FeedScreen,
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
});

TabNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];

     // You can do whatever you like here to pick the title based on the route name
    const headerTitle = routeName;

    return {
       headerTitle,
    };
};

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: TabNavigator,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access tab navigationOptions for each screen here also, is this what you want? This should work in react-navigation version 1,2.* , I'm not sure about 3.

```
screen: createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      firstTab: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
          firstStack: {
            screen: firstStackScreen
          },
          SecondStack: {
            screen: SecondStackScreen
            }
          }
        }),
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {}
      }
      secondTab: {
        screen: SecondTabScreen,
      }
```